# How to animate CN1 Slider progress on load

Tags: codenameone

Please can you help me work out how to build a Codenameone Slider control that simply animates its Progress when it renders initially, so the user sees the progress bar increase over the course of a few seconds.

[image]

My actual implementation is to use Chen's awesome [ArcProgress](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/CN1CircleProgress) control to show how far something has grown, so as the control renders the arc is filled to its 70% or so level over a few seconds. I have the image above all built and working so far.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to invoke `setValue` to indicate the current position. I'm guessing you don't see the progress moving because you're doing the progress on the EDT thus blocking painting.

All paint operations are performed on the EDT thread and so if your loading/processing code runs on that thread (the main thread) you're effectively blocking the paint operations. There's a long discussion of this in the [EDT section of the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/edt.html).

Comment: Good point. I was blocking the thread. But i'm not quite there - just putting the slider value into another thread works but renders the value in a single step (zero to 70%). I was after a fluid animation of the Slider value going from zero to 70% over the course of a few seconds. Technically it's not a Slider object i'm using but a Graphics object, where i'm drawShape() using a GeneralPath.arc(), as per Chen's example. If this can't be done, then it's not a blocker for me, just a nice to have if straight forward. Thanks

Comment: It's the other way around. You need to update the UI (the progress) on the EDT but do everything else off the EDT (in a separate thread) otherwise things won't update. Also if you take up too much CPU without yielding drawing just won't happen as CPU's aren't great multi-taskers even in multi-core scenarios.